# jQuery on click no focus on readonly input field (in Firefox)

Tags: jquery, focus, keyup, input-field

I'm trying to create an input field that shows realtime the number of characters in another input field. I don't want focus on that counter field when a user clicks on it and that field is readonly. In Chrome the field doesn't get a focus, only readonly is necessary, but in Firefox it still get a focus when I click on it. I tried to prevent this with for example blur() but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong or what is the solution for this?

```
$(function(){
$("input[type='text']").on("keyup", function(event){ 
    $(".counter").blur();
    $("#counter_1").val($(this).val().length);
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67Bpa/3/

Comment: you'd have better to not use an input then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just blur the field whenever it gets focus

```
$("#myFieldIdontWantFocusOn").on("focus", function(){
  $(this).blur();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/tJ6N8/)

EDIT:

Updated fiddle to incorporate A.Wolff's observation above.

Comment: +1 even i'd use as selector: `$("input[type='text'][readonly]")`

Comment: To make it complete I also added     $(this).css("cursor" , "default");

Comment: @JackZelig Your fiddle seems irrelevant to your answer.

Comment: Lol, yeah, it does, doesn't it. I wonder what happened there. I think it still answers the question, though.